# Getting GET or POST parameters via lambda functional

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Recently amazon has released Function Url in Lambda.

I just want to know if we can access Query parameters using it , without using the gateway API.

```
For example https://functionalurl.aws?id=123
```

I need to get 123

```
exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
   console.log(event);
   callback(null, {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: context,
        headers: {
          "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
        },
      });
};
```

Event is always null when I access the function url.

Comment: What is the auth type and are you signing the requests if auth type is not NONE.  Test with curl first

Comment: Auth type is NONE , yea I tested with CURL too , its null

Comment: Debug the function if it is reaching and if you are mapping the even correctly like https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-lambda-url-sam/blob/main/lambdas/app.py or run the cloudformation and test against it

Comment: There is an example of the query string in the event object as part of the Lambda Function URL documentation here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/urls-invocation.html#urls-payloads If your `event` object is null then something is seriously wrong. The `event` object should always be present, with some fields like the HTTP method always populated.